# angular2-meteor Static Resources

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I have just upgraded my project to `angular2-meteor@0.5.6` but when I try to test out [Static Resources](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor#static-resources) with style files by following the documentation [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/tree/master/atmosphere-packages/css-compiler#usage)

```
import styleUrl from './foo.less!url';

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  styleUrls: [styleUrl]
})
class Foo { }
```

I get this error message

> Unable to resolve some modules:
>
> "./foo.less!url" in
>   /Users/project/.../Foo.component.ts
>   (web.browser)

And when I try the code below

```
import style from './foo.less'

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  styles: [style]
})
class Foo { }
```

I get this error message on client's browser console

> zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.

Am I missing something?